# Proving an element is a unit when the function is surjective and injective

Tags: proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

Apologies with formatting. Nearly all the written n's are meant to be subscripts, but I can't quite figure that out yet

Let n ∈ $ℤ_n$ with n>1. Let $[a]_n$ ∈ $ℤ_n$ with $[a]_n$ not equal to $[0]_n$ and define a function

f:$ℤ_n$→$ℤ_n$ by f:$[b]_n$↦$[b]_n$*$[a]_n$

Prove that $[a]_n$ is a unit if and only if f is surjective and show $[a]_n$ is a unit if and only if f is injective.

I understand what it means to be a unit. I'm very confused as to how a function being surjective or injective will cause the element to be a unit itself.

Comment: Can you prove, say, that if $a$ is a unit, then $f$ is bijective?

Comment: To get $[a]_n$, type \$[a]_n\$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*:

As this is a map from a finite set to itself, $f$ injective $\iff f$ surjective ($\iff f$ bijective).

On the other hand, $[a_n]$ is a unit iff and only if $[1]_n$ is attained.